# How To Stop Miis From Fighting All The Time

Tags: tomodachi-life

Most of the day when I boot up the game, Miis have a fight. I really had enough of the fighting.
Nintendo, the company, are happy about the lifelong miis and their catchphrase Your Friends Your Story Your Life, so I find it weird when most of the Miis hate one of them.

Comment: I don't want to inactivate kids yet, but maybe soon because parents ambush me to take care of their children and remind me that their child grew up and is ready to be an independent person.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Tomodachi Life Wikia](http://tomodachi.wikia.com/wiki/Fight):

> The system that determines fights is entirely random-based. Nothing
>   the player does beforehand nor the Mii's Relationship levels will
>   determine when the two Miis will fight, and if they do, whenever the
>   fight is either a standard fight or a hostile fight. Two Miis that
>   have married have a higher chance of fighting against each other than
>   with other Miis. If the fight fails to be resolved, both Miis will be
>   removed from their respective relationship charts, setting their
>   relationships back to anonymous. If this occurs to two married Miis,
>   this will result in an immediate breakup.
>
> Each time the player starts up the game after several hours of not
>   playing, three fights will break out at random.

To sum this up, you Mii's fight at random or after several hours of not playing.